# MySQL how to convert decimal value to degree, minute, second

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a decimal value say `123.77`

Now i want to convert it into corresponding `degree`, `minute`, `second` value using MySQL.
I tried several ways but can't get the right answer. please help.

Comment: What were the ways that you tried?

Comment: Is this value in radians, decimal degrees, grads, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how,

- The whole units of degrees will remain the same (i.e. in 121.135° longitude, start with 121°).
- Multiply the decimal by 60 (i.e. .135 * 60 = 8.1).
- The whole number becomes the minutes (8').
- Take the remaining decimal and multiply by 60. (i.e. .1 * 60 = 6).
- The resulting number becomes the seconds (6"). Seconds can remain as a decimal.
- Take your three sets of numbers and put them together, using the symbols for degrees (°), minutes (‘), and seconds (") (i.e. 121°8'6" longitude)

Query,

```
SET @deci = 123.77;
SELECT FLOOR(@deci) Degrees,

       FLOOR((@deci - (FLOOR(@deci))) * 60) Minutes,

       ((@deci - (FLOOR(@deci))) * 60 -
       FLOOR((@deci - (FLOOR(@deci))) * 60)) * 60 SECONDS
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2139)

**[Online Conversion Tool (for checking)](http://web.library.uiuc.edu/asp/max/DD2DMS.asp)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by John Woo, while correct for positive values, will not give the correct results for negative values. I have adjusted his answer to take account of this.

```
SET @deci = -123.77;
SELECT SIGN(@deci)* FLOOR(ABS(@deci)) Degrees,
FLOOR((ABS(@deci) - (FLOOR(ABS(@deci)))) * 60) Minutes,
((ABS(@deci) - (FLOOR(ABS(@deci)))) * 60 -
FLOOR((ABS(@deci) - (FLOOR(ABS(@deci)))) * 60)) * 60 SECONDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out of the box, by borrowing a different Babylonian-based metric:

```
mysql> SELECT TIME_FORMAT("%H°%i'%s", SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(3600 * -1.234)));
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIME_FORMAT("%H°%i'%s", SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(3600 * -1.234)))  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| -01:14:02                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT TIME_FORMAT("%H°%i'%s", SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(3600 * -123.77)));
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIME_FORMAT("%H°%i'%s", SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(3600 * -123.77)))  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| -123:46:12                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(The `ROUND` is to avoid getting 3 decimal places in the answer.)